# Caching? div concerning images don't work on pc's that opened site first 3 hours after upload

Tags: html, css, caching, filezilla

Hi I'm kinda stuck on idea's to try to solve my problem since I don't have much experience concerning caches.

I'm currently working on this site of a business partner of me. 
I got his host, username and password so I'm litterary working as him using Filezilla.
I downloaded the entire site content from filezilla into a desktopfolder. 
I made a copy of it to work in and from there I made some changes in the .html and .css files.
In offline mode, everythings works perfectly as I want it.

Then I deleted the the sitecontent in Filezilla and replaced it with my changes.
Now the weird parts happen.

When I open the site online without www. prefix it works great
when I open the site online with www. prefix I can't see the images that are 
     placed within div's that purely concern the image
When a pc opened the site in the first 3 houres it was online, the div's don't 
     work
Also later on that specific pc can't make the div's to work
Pc's that opened the site only after these 3 houres have no problem at all

I've tried replacing the stylesheet and wait a couple hours, but caches seem to be made. and the result stays the same.

However this is no problem for the avarage customer since for them the site works, you can see what a hell this may be for me as developer and the owner, who offcourse opened the site right after I put it online.

Any suggestions might be usefull.

Comment: Did you cleared the cache of your browser?

Answer (score 0):

In most of the browsers you can use `F12` shortcut to see the developer tools. In Network tab you can see all files that are currently being loaded. You can see there if the file is being loaded from the server or from the local machine.

By pressing `CTRL+F5` (in Chrome and think in Firefox too) you are forcing cache to refresh.

Comment: Further investigation made me think it's just coincidence that the pc's on wich the div's didn't work are the same as those that that first opened it.

I removed all caching from my own pc, and i get the same result. I'm probably looking for something else then a caching problem, but i have no clue what els it could be.
I'm looking for something that makes my coding work on one pc, but not on the other. Allthought they're both using Chrome

Comment: If you are loading the stylesheet somehow dynamicly there could be problem that the browser is not refreshing it. Open the website's stylesheet in your browser (F12 -> Sources -> right click on your_file.css and open in new tab). Is it outdated ? If so just press F5 there and that should affect the website too. If it's not your scenario I have no other clue.

Answer (score 0):

If the PC is still loading in a cached version of the site, you can refresh the page and delete the cache by holding `Control + F5`.

Comment: Refreshing the cache doesn't help. I'm probably looking for something else than a caching-problem. Even a complete new browser gives the same problem for the concerning pc's.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I found the source of the problem.

I was using the css from a bought template which has some coding that malfunctions when ftp-uploading using ASCII
Uploading Binary solves the problem

The reason the did work on some computers was that they had the old css still cached. which was earlyer uploaded in binary instead of the same css files i uploaded in ASCII.